# In The Oregon Trail on Apple II / Mac, what is clothing for?

Tags: the-oregon-trail

The last version of The Oregon Trail I played had the farmer as the biggest multiplier (pre-teacher) and had graphical hunting. This was on the Apple II.

Except for the ability to trade (and particularly to the Indian river guides) **does clothing serve any particular purpose?**

Comment: @Wrigglenite The question is for one game that has about half a dozen variants under the exact same name, only differentiable by the system - subsequent releases had changes. OP specified that this is for the Apple II version. Why not tag the Apple II?

Comment: @Trish Fair enough, I didn't realize there were differences between consoles. Feel free to suggest an edit again.

Comment: "I just played this game again and bought no clothes. There was no problem. I noticed no increase in ill-health or anything. Everybody got to Willamette Valley in good health and I ended up with 9400+ points. Interesting to note that the score credited me for one set of clothes. But I absolutely did not have any clothes and I checked my status before getting to the last landmark to confirm this. So apparently your settlers can travel the trail totally nude with no negative repercussions. Fantastic." [penny-arcade.com](https://forums.penny-arcade.com/discussion/156653/oregon-trail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clothes are only useful for bartering with traders or Indians. I did not have the opportunity to play the original on the Apple II, but I found an online version that is exactly like DOS version. The graphics may be different compared to the Apple II. You can play it here: https://archive.org/details/msdos_Oregon_Trail_The_1990

I played through this many times for fun, and I have found no other purpose for clothes than the ones you stated.